# Doctrine ManyToMany StateFieldPathExpression error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have read a bunch of questions here on SO about this error but still cannot get rd of it. I have 3 entities - Site, User and Tags. One site can have one unique user, but different users may have same tags and vice versa. One tag in its table  has a FK to a user and to a site. I am trying to display all tags that are related to one particular site with the following code:

```
->add('tags','entity', array(
'class'=> 'MyBundle:Tags',
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($siteid)
{
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.asiteid = :siteid')
    ->setParameter('siteid', $siteid);
}
```

Also I tried this:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($siteid) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->join('\MyBundle\Entity\Mysites','ta', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,'t.asiteid=ta.id')
            ->where('t.asiteid = :asiteid')
            ->setParameter('asiteid', $siteid);}
```

Property mapping in Tags entity is as follows:

```
 manyToMany:
    userid:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\User
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            userid:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
    asiteid:
        targetEntity: \MyBundle\Entity\Mysites
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: asiteid
        inversedBy: id
        joinColumns:
            siteid:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

But in any case I get [Semantical Error] line 0, col 113 near 'asiteid=ta.id': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected. Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by changing from ManyToMany to ManyToOne. I [regenerated entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) from existing DB and everything worked fine.